# Spyder Notebook Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython, anaconda, spyder

I'm using the spyder notebook from anaconda 2. The first line of my code is:

```
get_ipython().magic('matplotlib inline')
```

which returns the following error message

```
 get_ipython().magic('matplotlib inline')
NameError: name 'get_ipython' is not defined
```

I'm new to python so any help would be greatly appreciated .

Answer (score 1):

You need to first import `get_ipython` from `IPython` module.

Comment: I tried adding import IPython to the first line of my code. Do I need to add something else?

Comment: from IPython import get_ipython